# Is pivotal cloud foundry is support to windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services, pivotal-tc

I am new to cloud deployment,i started to learn it so i tried to install PCF in machine(windows 7 32bit) but i can get pcf(pivotal cloud foundry)windows 64 only,i cannot get the windows 32 bit version.

Is pivotal cloud foundry is not support to windows7 32 bit?

Comment: Why would you even want to use Windows 7 at this point? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are referring to by Pivotal Cloud Foundry here, but I'll cover a couple possibilities.

1. [Pivotal Cloud Foundry the Platform](https://docs.pivotal.io/platform/application-service/2-8/overview/intro.html). This is an entire platform. It runs on top of popular IaaS' like (GCP, AWS, Azure, OpenStack & vSphere). It is multiple VMs, most of which run Linux. It is possible to install a Windows layer for running Windows apps, but that will not be Windows 7. It will run Windows Server & at the time of writing this it's Windows Server 2019.
2. [PCF Dev](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcfdev/) is a tool provided for running a shrunken down version of what I described in #1 as a VM on your laptop. This can be [run on a Windows laptop, but requires Windows 10+](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/install-windows.html)